# How to override FastAPI's predefined validation error for UUID?

Tags: python, fastapi, uuid, pydantic

I want to use my own custom response_body when a UUID validation fails. How can I do that while retaining the UUID typing on the handler like so?

```
app.get("/streams/{stream_id}")
async def get_stream(stream_id: UUID):
  ...
```

I could replace UUID with str and then use the UUID object to attempt a ValueError exception if the id is invalid. But I'm trying to figure out if there's a FastAPI way. The [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params-numeric-validations/) only allows for numerical validation of path parameters.

How can I use my own validation response for UUID params?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that fails or produces the wrong output as well as the desired output.

Comment: The minimal reproducible code is the handler above. You could use it with literally any return value (return "ok") and use it with an invalid UUID in the API to see FastAPI's default error. That is the error I want to override.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, rewriting error message is not straight forward for inline params as the pydantic class definitions.

However, you can go as simple as that:

```py
    @app.get("/streams/{stream_id}")
    async def get_stream(stream_id: str):
        try:
            stream_id_validated =  UUID(stream_id)
        except ValueError as e:
            return JSONResponse(
            status_code=400,
            content={"message": f"Oops! your streem id is not a valid UUID..."},
        )
    
        return stream_id_validated
```

Comment: Yes, this is a potential fix to my problem. I wanted to introduce a solution that would not incur duplicate code across my handlers. Thanks!

Comment: move it as a function , and raise custom exception UUIDValueError, then catch it with fastapi exception handler